# Find year index from month indexes

Tags: .net, indexing

How to find year index from a given month index?

For example, if the monthly array has 120 elements:

```
[0, 1, 2, ... , 119]
```

When I'm looping this array I need to get out what year index the item is. Year index in this case would have 10 elements

```
[0, 1, ... , 9].
```

Below the results needed:

```
Month item index   Year item index
0-11                0
12-23               1
24-35               2
36-47               3
...                 ...
108-119             9
```

I believe using MOD operator would do this but it needs some adjustments.

Comment: At risk of being the one who points out the elephant in the room here: that's not a .NET question, that's calculus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double i = month / 12;
i = Math.Floor(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would simply integer-divide the month-indices:

```
int month = months[i];
int year = month / 12;
```

Results in:

```
Month item index  | Year item index  | Result
---------------------------------------------
0-11              |  0               |  0
12-23             |  1               |  1
24-35             |  2               |  2
36-47             |  3               |  3
...               |  ...             |  ...
108-119           |  9               |  9
```

Just make sure your month item indices are integers.